# IIS 10 - Process multiple requests from the same IP address

Tags: windows, iis

In our internal network, we have many applications hosted on different pools. User X might load a report which sends a request to the web server to run. Whilst this request is running, user X may also try and load the home page in order to perform another task.

However, User X cannot access the webpage as the report is still running and it appears IIS won't allow more than 1 request from the same IP address to be processed. It will wait for the latest request to finish before it moves on to the next one.

Is there anything in the configuration to allow IIS to process all requests from the same IP at the same time no matter how many User X sends (This is all an internal system)

Comment: "However, User X cannot access the webpage as the report is still running and it appears IIS won't allow more than 1 request from the same IP address to be processed. It will wait for the latest request to finish before it moves on to the next one." However, that's not true for others' web apps on IIS. Do you happen to have some locks in your own code? Without seeing your code or a sample project that demonstrating the behavior, no concrete answer can be made.

Comment: Smells like someone does not understand the price of having automatic sessions (which requires everythign using a session to be serialized).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to configure IP and Domain Restrictions in the web site features of IIS Manager. But it could also be an application functionality.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/dynamicipsecurity/

If you check in IIS Manager > Sites > [Web site] > IP Address and Domain Restrictions and there aren't any entries, it may be an application configuration.  It may also be present at the server level node.

If there are entries, you can right-click on them and select Edit Dynamic Restriction Settings to view or configure the maximum concurrent requests.

[image: IP Address and Domain Restrictions]